# Roslyn error installing scriptcs

Tags: chocolatey, scriptcs

I'm installing [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) using [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), but I keep getting the error seen in the picture.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the error. My package source for [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) was set to another than the official NuGet package source. Changing it back to the default solved the issue.

So if you get this error, ensure to check your package manager settings.